# Exclude property on query neo4j client

Tags: neo4jclient

I'm making an application which is similar to a small network.
I have this class :

```
class Person
{
    public string Email {get; set;}
    public string Password {get; set;}
    public int Age {get; set;}
    public long Birthday {get;set;}
    ... 30 properties more
}
```

I have this query :

```
_graphClient.Cypher.Match ("n:Person")
    .Where<Person>(n => n.Email == info.Email)
    .Return(n => n.As<Person>)
```

But I want my query ignore the password and return all other properties.

Exactly, I want it to be:

```
{
 Email: "email_1",
 Age : 10,
 Birthday : 1000
 ... 30 properties more
}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three options I can think of, but I think only one is really viable for you. You can attach the attribute `[JsonIgnore]` to your `Password` property - but this will stop it being serialized ever - and I don't think you want that.

The second option is to use an Anonymous type for your return, so something like:

```
.Return(n => new {
        Email = n.As<Person>().Email,
        /* etc */
    })
```

But I think that will mean you'll write a lot of code, which I imagine you'd rather avoid.

The final option is to have something like:

```
public class Person {
    public string Email { get; set; }
    /* All other properties, except Password */
}

public class PersonWithPassword : Person {
    public string Password { get;set; }
}
```

Then use `Person` where you are, and `PersonWithPassword` where you need the password.

You might find you have a problem if you have a Membership set up to use `Person` as is - in which case, you'd do something like:

```
public class PersonWithoutPassword {
    public string Email { get; set; }
    /* All other properties, except Password */
}

public class Person : PersonWithoutPassword {
    public string Password { get;set; }
}
```

and in your return - you'd return:

```
Return(n => n.As<PersonWithoutPassword>())
```

instead.